# Visual Studio Writes Partial Data to Excel File

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis

I have a visual studio package that does not write all the data needed to a blank excel file.

More specifically, the package goes through these steps:

1. Copies a template excel file to overwrite a shell file.
2. Connects to a SQL DB.
3. Runs a Select Statement.
4. Converts one column to unicode.
5. Pastes to shell file.

There are a few more steps afterward (like emailing the excel file) but those work fine.

The issue comes up for step 4. when Visual Studio or SSIS runs the package, I pull about 1400 rows. When I just run the select statement in SQL Server Management Studio or as a connection in Excel I pull about 2800 rows. 2800 is the right number.

I've tried building the process from scratch (excel files, connection files, etc.) but that rebuild elicits the same result. It's like Visual Studio just doesn't like the select statement. Double checked the mappings - all good. The data is pasting and being delivered fine, just not enough. No errors on visual studio either - it gives me that lovely (albeit confusing) check mark.

This was running as an automated package for about a year before this happened and I have no explanation. Seriously a headscratcher.

The only other clue I have is that when I pull the data manually with the select statement, there are no null values in a particular column, but when I run the package with that exact same select statement the output contains a null in the referenced column - almost as if the select statement in Visual Studio is pulling slightly different data than the manual pull, but the statements are exactly the same, so I don't know why that would be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which1400 rows make it in the final file? the first 1400, the last 1400, an apparently random selection?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you attached a profiler to the database to capture the exact statement being executed on the SQL server? SSIS wraps SQL statements in its own little magic before running them.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the selection appears fairly random. The data is ordered by an ID number and the last ID in the 1400 set is about 800 below the last ID in the 2400 set. So there's significant data missing, but the data isn't being simply cut in half. There's a more complex filter being applied.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I had not, but that's a good idea! I'll try that and report back (will have to look up how to attach a profiler first :P)

Comment: @Cobalt21: Assuming you have it installed, launch SQL Server Profiler, then just connect to the server. There are other various switches and filters, but if the traffic isn't heavy, you can probably just start a trace and watch the statements come in.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before. The timeout was set to an low value on the connection and caused it to only pull part of data before the timeout hit and killed the connection. Make sure you are not swallowing any exceptions and double check your timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying folks!

In the end, I solved the issue by completely remaking the package. While trying your solutions above, I was using the same file but building the connections and queries from scratch. Once I started from a new file it ran without error.

I guess to all those new folks to Visual Studio - always consider remaking the file from nothing!